# Using python variables in ansible

Tags: variables, ansible, ansible-facts

I tried this one

```
---
- name: py
  hosts: master
  tasks:
  - name:
    command: /home/vagrant/test.py
    register: csvfile
    changed_when: false
  - debug:
      var: csvfile
  - name: Create csvfile directories
    file:
      path: "/tmp/{{ item.host }}_{{ item.app }}"
      state: directory
    with_dict: "{{ csvfile }}"
```

`Test.py` results are:

```
{'key': 'stdout_lines', 'value': ["{'host': '123', 'app': 'abc'}", "{'host': '2345', 'app': 'def'}", "{'host': '8484', 'app': 'ghju'}", "{'host': '89393', 'app': 'yruru'}"]}
```

and i'm getting error at `"/{{ item.host }}_{{ item.app }}"`

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

The registered variable *csvfile* must have the attribute *stdout_lines*

```
csvfile:
  stdout_lines:
    - {'host': '123', 'app': 'abc'}
    - {'host': '2345', 'app': 'def'}
    - {'host': '8484', 'app': 'ghju'}
    - {'host': '89393', 'app': 'yruru'}
```

The simple loop should do the job

```
  - name: Create csvfile directories
    file:
      path: "/tmp/{{ item.host }}_{{ item.app }}"
      state: directory
    loop: "{{ csvfile.stdout_lines }}"
```

---

The `key/value` decomposition was added very probably by *with_dict*.  Please confirm, update and fix the question. Post the output of the task

```
  - debug:
      var: csvfile
```

Comment: currently we are using V2.3 and Python 2.7. loops aren't working.

Answer (score 0):

*There are a bunch of things wrong, so while this is an "answer" because it is too big to fit into a comment here on S.O., it is not the fix to your problem because there is so much wrong with your code.*

As your debug output demonstrates, the `register:` captures the output of the *whole task*, and not just the output from your program. Thus, at the very least you would need `with_dict: "{{ csvfile.stdout }}"` but that, too, will not work because the output is not an interoperability format that ansible can use. Just because it is written in python and your script is written in python does not mean they can communicate

You will need to have the `test.py` call `json.dump` or `json.dumps` on the results, and not just `print()` or `repr` or whatever it is calling now, so that the output can be parsed by ansible back into an actual data structure in your playbook

Then, what happens next depends on whether you continue to write out each dictionary from `test.py` on a per-line basis, or you choose to package them all into a list of dictionaries and dump that as JSON

Start by fixing the output from `test.py` to be parseable by ansible, and we'll go from there

Comment: Thanks for your help, As i cant post everything here i posted as an answer can you please guide me on this

Answer (score 0):

Sumanth, you can try the same approach but using with_items:

```
  - name: Create csvfile directories
    file:
      path: "/tmp/{{ item.host }}_{{ item.app }}"
      state: directory
    with_items: "{{ csvfile.stdout_lines }}"
```

Comment: The offending line appears to be:

  file: splunkapps.csv
    path: "/tmp/{{ item.host }}_{{ item.app }}"
        ^ here
We could be wrong, but this one looks like it might be an issue with
missing quotes.  Always quote template expression brackets when they
start a value. For instance:

    with_items:
      - {{ foo }}

Should be written as:

    with_items:
      - "{{ foo }}"

I go this error

Comment: If you are testing with values with special chars, you can always set {{ item.host | string}} or {{ item.app | string}} to cast it to strings.

Comment: I added | string as mentioned; I am with this error

FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "with_dict expects a dict"}

Comment: Have you added it to the csvfile.stdout_lines or to each item? Could you put a snippet of code of how this is actually looking right now? You can as well, create a debug with the following code [just before the Create csvfile directories]:
`
- name: Debugging csvfile
  debug:
    var: "{{ item }}"
  with_items: "{{ csvfile.stdout_lines }}"
`
This will output what is the item content, to see if we have to deep dive into this.

Comment: ---
- name: py
  hosts: master
  tasks:
  - name:
    command: /home/vagrant/test.py
    register: csvfile
    changed_when: false
  - debug:
      var: csvfile
  - name: Create csvfile directories
    file:
      path: "/tmp/{{ item.AppName | string }}_{{ item.SealID | string }}"
      state: directory
    with_dict: "{{ csvfile.stdout_lines }}"

Comment: Please, add the output of the debug that you got. You can add the `- name` parameter before `- debug` [but you need to remove the `- ` from debug] to spot it in your run. This will actually provide some insight about what are we looping actually.

Comment: TASK [Debugging csvfile] 
----
ok: [192.168.121.72] => (item={'host': '123', 'AppName': 'abc'}) => {
    "<class 'dict'>": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!",
    "item": "{'host': '123', 'AppName': 'abc'}"
}

TASK [Create csvfile directories] 
----
fatal: [192.168.121.72]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "with_dict expects a dict"}
        to retry, use: --limit @/home/i737119/vms/host2/splunk.retry

Comment: ---
- name: py
  hosts: master
  tasks:
  - name:
    command: /home/vagrant/test.py
    register: csvfile
    changed_when: false
  - debug:
      var: csvfile
  - name: Debugging csvfile
    debug:
      var: "{{ item }}"
    with_items: "{{ csvfile.stdout_lines }}"
  - name: Create csvfile directories
    file:
      path: "/tmp/{{ item.AppName | string }}_{{ item.Host | string }}"
      state: directory
    with_dict: "{{ csvfile.stdout_lines }}"